# Doctrine Exception - The table with name ['table_name'] already exists

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, migration

I've created a single Entity with it's properties, getters and setters then I ran:

```
$ php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Everything worked and the table was created in the database. Now I have a couple of new Entities that I also want to migrate. But when I run:

```
$ php  bin/console doctrine:schema:validate
```

or

```
$ php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff
```

I get this:

> ```
>   [Mapping]  OK - The mapping files are correct.
>
>
>   [Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]                     
>   The table with name ['table_name'] already exists.
> ```

Of course the table already exists. I just created it. But I don't wanna remove the existing table's Entity. I also don't want Doctrine to ignore it because I created new associations. So what's wrong? How can I make Doctrine recognize existing tables and try to identify changes in it, instead of stopping the process when it finds it.

Comment: Can you post all your entities? You may have two entities with the same name?

Comment: [albert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2751236/albert) - I copied the structure of the first Entity and neglected to change the @ORM\Table(name="[table_name]") field. So it was repeated. Big duh! to me. Thx.

Comment: I thought this the error :)

Comment: Take a look at your migration files then. It is not that hard: They have names sorted on datetime and only two methods, Up Method for upgrades and Down for downgrade or reverse, Just think logic and look what should be deleted or changed. You can also delete a file but you will have to delete its name in the database too in that case